# Python write dictionary to csv with header

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a specific python dictionary to csv with header. I have looked at other questions but none of them have the similar dictionary structure as mine:

```
myDic = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 15}

header = ["word", "count"]

with open('myFile.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(myDic)
```

What I got is only `word,count` in my CSV file. I am using python 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to write the entire dictionary as a row. Instead, write each row separately.

Please see here for more details:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

As an example please see the following usage:

```
import csv

myDic = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 15}
with open('myFile.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['word', 'count']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for key in myDic:
        writer.writerow({'word': key, 'count': myDic[key]})
```

Let me know if this helps. I didn't test the code... but I may before you see the answer.

**Edit**
Yeah tested, seems to work fine. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi, this works ok except my csv has empty lines between rows

Comment: "has empty lines between rows" - Well, that's odd. Did you include `newline=''` as specified in Tr1gZer0's answer?

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
import csv

myDic = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 15}

header = ["word", "count"]

with open('myFile.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header) # write the header
    for k,v in myDic.items():
        writer.writerow([k,v])
```

Comment: Hi, this works ok except my csv has empty lines between rows

Comment: Hi, as suggested by @Justin Ezequiel, i need to specify `newline=' '`

Comment: I had the same initial question and vote this as the most complete answer thanks

Comment: can you please give an example where the keys are the first line of the CSV and the values are the proceeding lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `DictWriter` in that way, it is designed for `key=column_header` and `value=[row_values]`.

You can instead iterate your dictionary and use `csv.writerow`

```py
import csv


myDic = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 15}

header = ["word", "count"]

with open('myFile.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(header)
    for k, v in myDic.items():
        w.writerow([k, v])
```

or as juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out you can `writerows` directly on the `.items()`.

```py
with open('myFile.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    w.writerow(header)
    w.writerows(myDic.items())
```

However, storing your information for your csv in a dictionary in this way is very limiting since it can only ever be two columns so ensure that is an acceptable choice before continuing down this path.

Comment: Or just `w.writerows(myDic.items())`

Comment: That makes more sense. I wasn't thinking.

Comment: Hi, this works ok except my csv has empty lines between rows –

Comment: I can write a better response in the morning since I'm on mobile now but you may need to specify newline.

Comment: Hi, as suggested by @Justin Ezequiel, i need to specify `newline=' '`

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Lol

Comment: I copied your code and tried to run it and got : w.writerow(header)

NameError: name 'w' is not defined. can you please give an example where the keys are the first line of the CSV and the values are the proceeding lines.

Comment: You're missing the initialization of your csv writer `w = csv.writer(f)` f.e.